# Ignoring container elements through JAXB customization

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl, jaxb, jax-ws

I am struggling with a simple JAXB customization issue. I have an schema like this. (its actually a snippet of Bing Maps Web Services schema)

```
 <xs:complexType name="GeocodeOptions">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Count" nillable="true" type="xs:int" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Filters" nillable="true" type="ArrayOfFilterBase" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfFilterBase">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="FilterBase" nillable="true" type="FilterBase" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now when I generate java classes using wsimport, it creates code structure like:

```
public class GeocodeOptions implements Serializable {
...
    public ArrayOfFilterBase getFilters() {
    ...
    }

    public void setFilters(ArrayOfFilterBase value) {
    ...
    }
}

public class ArrayOfFilterBase implements Serializable {
...
    public List<FilterBase> getFilterBaseList() {
    ...
    }
}
```

As you notice ArrayOfFilterBase is a container class which I would like to omit. I would like to have the getFilterBaseList() method directly inside GeocodeOptions class.

Is it possible to do it through JAXB customization? I searched hard for it but could not find a solution.

Thanks for your help.

Regards
Nabeel Mukhtar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can omit the container using the @XmlElementWrapper annotation. Your code should look something like this:

```
public class GeocodeOptions implements Serializable {
       @XmlElementWrapper(name = "...")
       @XmlElement(name = "...")
      public List<FilterBase> getFilterBaseList() {
       ...
      }
}
```